# Rails serving files per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, file

Hey. In my rails application each client has a file. This file must not be accessible to public, only to the user (authenticated user). How would you implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need put this file in other place than /public directory.

After you can use send_file in your controller to send file by user.

Comment: make sure you take care on this performance caveat: http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right